# I want to filter List of objects depend on Date

Tags: dart

i stucked in filter list depend on date condition like what i make in c#

```
widget.VarData = widget.Data.where((x)=>x.Date. > DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -7)));
```

it show me error that datetime class doesnot have >

any recommendation

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` has [`isAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.15.0/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) and [`isBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.15.0/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html). Since `DateTime` has both a date/time and a time zone, it's not a single-dimensional value. That's why it doesn't use the simple `<` for comparison.

So:

```dart
var weekAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 7));
widget.varData = widget.data.where((x) => x.date.isAfter(weekAgo));
```

(It seemed wasteful to create a new `DateTime` object on each comparison).